# How do they integrate this exponential?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponentiation

Below, I tired to integrate te^(-j2pi*t) from 0 to 1. But am not getting what my professor got for n not equal to zero, which is also shown. I tried LIATE but am always getting something with an exponential in it, I am not getting -1/(jn2pi). How did he get it.

[image]

Comment: You've made a mistake when finding the antiderivative of your v.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that $e^{-j2n\pi}=\color{blue}1$ !
$$\int_0^1 te^{at}dt=(\frac ta-\frac1{a^2})e^{at}\big|_0^1=(\frac1a-\frac1{a^2})\color{blue}1-(\frac0a-\frac1{a^2})1=\frac1a.$$